# Xamarin UItest query for similar elements

Tags: xamarin, uitest

[Sceenshot][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5pkY.pngstrong text

I am trying to locate two similar elements ("Meer info"). On a previous build of the same app it works with this query:

_bewering1_helpbutton = x => x.Marked("De volgende gegegevens zijn bij ons bekend").Sibling("ImageRenderer");

Now this query gave 0 results. I think the reason is that our developer has changed the code in some places.

Is there any other way I can locate the elements "Meer info". It is not possible to use "Index" because on some small screens the locators are not visible at the same time.

Comment: Welcome, please take a look at [ask], [Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

I notice your `REPL`

[image]

You can use `id` to locate the elements "Meer info".

For testing, I use two `Entry`s, here is `REPL`

[image]

when I tab it, I enter the new value to it with

```
app.EnterText(c=>c.Marked("NoResourceEntry-2"), "1234567890123456")
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue